# Circuit to Interface 12v DC motor with raspberry pi2 using L293d ic for Forward,reverse,Stop function

Tags: hardware

I want to interface 12 dc motor with Raspberry pi 2. I tried by switching the transistor for forwarding and stopping the motor.How can i do  it by doing with L293d ic.By giving 12v in L293d vcc2 pin does it affect my pi.please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: If properly connected the Pi will not be damaged.  Neither would any other computer.  There must be thousands of examples of hooking up a microprocessor to a L293D.  Have you tried googling?

Comment: related http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/controlling-two-motors-with-an-l293d http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37051/using-an-l293d-chip-to-control-a-motor-with-a-separate-power-supply

Comment: The [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-9-controlling-a-dc-motor/overview) linked from the first of Ghanima's linked questions seems to provide a pretty thorough walkthrough of hooking up an L293D to a Pi. Looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi pins only outputs 3.3V or 5V. If you need to control a 12V device you need to plug it to another power supply (or a power suply with different outputs for 5v and 12v as a standard PC power supply). Then you can control GPIO with [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/).